# Full page in Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am having `iframe` of **250 X 250**, in which there is an image of **472 X 107**.

Have look at snippet.

```html
<iframe src="https://i.imgur.com/NYLlgwU.png" width="250px" height="250px"></iframe>
```

Now I want to show full image in the `iframe`, without scrolling.

> Note 1: Size of Iframe should remain same i.e **250 X 250**.
>
> Note 2: Size of an image can change.
>
> Note 3: It is not necessary it will be always an image. It can be pdf or text file too.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `scrolling="no"` attribute to the `iframe` and tweak it using css a little.

```css
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://i.imgur.com/NYLlgwU.png" class="img-responsive" scrolling="no" width="250" height="250"></iframe>
```

See [Codepen too](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZXKYY)

Comment: Is the image not contained in the `iframe`? How come you want the image to be bigger than it's **fixed sized** container?

Comment: The image is stored in the database, and it's not necessary that all images will have **250 X 250** size.

Comment: As my `iframe` is in **table**, I can't extend the size of `iframe` more than 250 x 250

Comment: And it is not compulsory that it will have only **image**. It can also have **pdf**

Comment: No, your update didn't solve the problem. See:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131440/full-page-in-iframe#comment79225524_46131615

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154031/discussion-between-babalu-pandey-and-samuel-asor).